# Events sent to Google Analytics with Gabba don't have a hostname

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-analytics, gabba

I'm using [Gabba](https://github.com/hybridgroup/gabba) to send events to Google Analytics from my rails back-end.

When I send events, the "hostname" is not set (in Content > Events > click on an event > set "Second dimension" to hostname).

---

[image]

---

Here's a simplified version of how I send my events:

```
gabba ||= Gabba::Gabba.new(Settings.google_analytics.ua_code, "none")
gabba.identify_user(cookies[:__utma], cookies[:__utmz])
gabba.event("Submissions", "submit_for_review")
```

My question is: **where does Google Analytics pick up the hostname from?**

I thought it was from the utmz cookie, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
g = Gabba::Gabba.new("CODE", "mydomain.com")
```

Comment: Yeah, this works, but I basically wanted to avoid having to do that. I thought that was possible since on the client side, I was setting `_setDomainName` to `none`.