# gabba gem not tracking different domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, universal-analytics, measurement-protocol, gabba

I have a UA account which is connected to the following domain: 
http://www.mytestdomain.com with the following account id UA-123456-1

When i am using the Gem to track the domain it works well:

```
Gabba::Gabba.new('UA-123456-1', 'http://www.mytestdomain.com', user_agent).page_view('index', 'index.html')
```

But other domains can't be track:

```
Gabba::Gabba.new('UA-123456-1', 'http://www.notmydomain.com', user_agent).page_view('index', 'index.html')
```

What should i do to track others domains as well ?

related : [Events sent to Google Analytics with Gabba don't have a hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420285/events-sent-to-google-analytics-with-gabba-dont-have-a-hostname?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the hostname "http://www.notmydomain.com" you should probably be using `request.host`. so:

```
Gabba::Gabba.new('UA-123456-1', request.host, request.user_agent)
            .page_view('index', request.fullpath)
```

If you still have problems seeing the hostname, make sure you don't have any filters filtering out the content in Google Analytics.

Also have a look at [GabbaGMP](https://github.com/fuzzyjulz/gabba-gmp), it makes it a little simpler in terms of coding, and also allows you to do geo tracking, which Gabba doesn't allow (doesn't currently support eCommerce analytics)