# universal analytics domain tacking is not working properly

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, measurement-protocol

I have a UA account which is connected to the following domain: http://www.mytestdomain.com with the following account id UA-123456-1

I am not using analytics.js because this code is fired from the server via ruby Gem.

When i am trying to track linked domain it works well:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4.4sh&utmn=7108653235&utmhn=mytestdomain.com&utmcs=UTF-8&utmul=en-us&utmdt=PAGE_VIEW_TITLE&utmhid=6413225625&utmp=4.html&utmac=UA-123465-6&utmcc=__utma%3D1.197975304100145214523.2102153242.1405604565.1405604565.15%3B%2B__utmz%3D1.1405604565.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B&utmr=&utmip=
```

But other domains can't be track:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4.4sh&utmn=7108653235&utmhn=notmydomain.com&utmcs=UTF-8&utmul=en-us&utmdt=PAGE_VIEW_TITLE&utmhid=6413225635&utmp=4.html&utmac=UA-123465-6&utmcc=__utma%3D1.197975304100145214523.2102153242.1405604565.1405604565.15%3B%2B__utmz%3D1.1405604565.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B&utmr=&utmip=
```

What should i do to track others domains as well ?

related: [gabba gem not tracking different domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761941/gabba-gem-not-tracking-different-domains)

Comment: I have a couple of questions: 1) What do you mean by track other domains? Are these domains you control? 2) I don't see what the Gabba gem gets you that analytics.js doesn't? Why are you using it?

Comment: do you have any filters in place that are excluding traffic from other domains?

Comment: Also, on the surface, it seems to me that you (or the gem you use) is basically attempting to reproduce a js generated request.. For example, that `utmcc` param.. the value in there includes a hash or checksum of the domain (I do not know GA's exact algo for generating it), so GA may be rejecting it from that too. GA has a [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) for sending data in server-side..

Comment: I don't have filters.

Comment: The Gem is using the Measurement Protocol API.